# Restrict SSH server tunneling port

Tags: tcp, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

I have a SSH server running OpenSSH. I want to use it to setup a SOCKS server so that my friends in China can use it to access websites such as twitter. I want to enforce two restrictions: 1. no shell access, 2. only port 80 and 443 allowed.

My question is, how to enforce the second restriction? I tried to put the following line in /home/tunuser/.ssh/authorized_keys:
permitopen=":80",permitopen=":443",no-pty ...

I use ssh -D option, and the browser used SOCKS proxy. The ssh client logged in successfully, but my web browser can't establish a tunnel. The error message on the ssh server says the tunnel is not allowed.

After I removed the two "permitopen" options, my browser can successful browse.

Does openssh support "restrict only port, allow any host"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is not possible to use `wildcard` in `hostnames`

```
No pattern matching is performed on the specified hostnames, 
they must be literal domains or addresses.
```

Man Page for `permitopen`

```
permitopen="host:port"
         Limit local ``ssh -L'' port forwarding such that it may only connect 
to the specified host and port.  IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing
the address in square brackets.  Multiple permitopen options may be applied 
separated by commas.  No pattern matching is performed on the specified                 
hostnames, they must be literal domains or addresses.  A port specification 
of * matches any port.
```

Comment: I want the wildcard on the host, not the port. Seems "*:80" doesn't work.

Comment: Is your `OpenSSH` version `6.0`?

Comment: It's 6.2p2 on Fedora 19 x64.

Comment: Sorry buddy, just read the `man`, it is not possible.Edited the answer.

Comment: Yes and there is another thing: "Multiple permitopen options may be applied separated by commas" which is wrong in the OP